# Implementación de watershed en C++

Tags: c++, imagen, algoritmos

estoy tratando de implementar el algoritmo  de Watershed en C++. He implementado un código a partir de unos pasos pero no he obtenido el resultado esperado. 
El resultado que he obtenido al aplicar watershed es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado que espero obtener es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para hacer watershed, calculo el gradiente de la imagen de entrada que cargo en una matrix aplicando el operador Sobel o Prewitt, da igual.

El código que implementa watershed es el siguiente:

```
    void Watershed() {

stack<punto> s;
punto p, p1, p2, p3, p4;

C_Matrix prueba3 (Gradiente.FirstRow(), Gradiente.LastRow(), Gradiente.FirstCol(), Gradiente.LastCol(), -1);

int auxU, auxV, Eaux, L=1;

for (double g = Gradiente.Min(); g <= Gradiente.Max(); g++) {

    for (int i = Gradiente.FirstRow(); i <= Gradiente.LastRow(); i++) {
        for (int j = Gradiente.FirstCol(); j <= Gradiente.LastCol(); j++) {
            if (Gradiente(i, j) == g) {
                p.Guarda(i, j);
                s.push(p);
            }

            while (s.empty() == 0) {
                p = s.top();
                s.pop();
                auxU = p.x;
                auxV = p.y;
                Eaux = -1;


                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    if (i == 0)
                        p1.Guarda(auxU - 1, auxV - 1);
                    else if (i == 1)
                        p1.Guarda(auxU, auxV - 1);
                    else if (i == 2)
                        p1.Guarda(auxU + 1, auxV - 1);
                    else if (i == 3)
                        p1.Guarda(auxU - 1, auxV);
                    else if (i == 4)
                        p1.Guarda(auxU + 1, auxV);
                    else if (i == 5)
                        p1.Guarda(auxU - 1, auxV + 1);
                    else if (i == 6)
                        p1.Guarda(auxU, auxV + 1);
                    else
                        p1.Guarda(auxU + 1, auxV + 1);

                    if (p1.x >= Gradiente.FirstRow() && p1.x <= Gradiente.LastRow()
                        && p1.y >= Gradiente.FirstCol() && p1.y <= Gradiente.LastCol()) {
                        if (prueba3(p1.x, p1.y) > 0) {
                            if (Eaux == -1) {
                                Eaux = prueba3(p1.x, p1.y);
                            }
                            else if (prueba3(p1.x, p1.y) != Eaux)
                                Eaux = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (auxU >= Gradiente.FirstRow() && auxU <= Gradiente.LastRow()
                    && auxV >= Gradiente.FirstCol() && auxV <= Gradiente.LastCol()) {

                    if (Eaux >= 0) {
                        prueba3(auxU, auxV) = Eaux;
                    }
                    else {
                        prueba3(auxU, auxV) = L;
                        L++;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    C_Print("Se sale");
                    C_PrintNum("AuxU", auxU);
                    C_PrintNum("AuxV", auxV);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
C_PrintNum("L = ", L);

double max = prueba3.Max();
if (max > 255.0) {
    prueba3.Stretch(0, 255);
}

aux = C_Image(prueba3);
```

}

Me falta algo o simplemente la implementación sobre la que me he basado era erronea?

Comment: Hay una cuantas clases y funciones en tu código que desconocemos completamente... todas las `C_*`, `Gradiente`, `stack` (no se sabe si es la implementación de la `stl`). Te sugeriría empezar probando sistemas más sencillos (una única región) para entender por qué tu algoritmo de inundación no funciona correctamente

Comment: Estoy utilizando una librería que tiene preparada la carga de imágenes en matrices, prueba 3 es una matriz del mismo tamaño que la imagen gradiente inicializada toda a -1. Gradiente es el gradiente de la imagen de entrada que calculo aplicando el operador Sobell y stack es la definida en `#include <stack>"`. Punto es una clase que he creado para guardar la posición x e y dentro de la pila. @eferion